# Comparing fragments of a single file or parts of two distinct files

Tags: phpstorm, diff, jetbrains-ide

In JetBrains' IDEs (PhpStorm) -- is there any way to compare two fragments of a single file or parts of two distinct files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and it should work for both cases. First select the first text that you want to compare and copy it. Then select the second text, right click and select "compare with clipboard"

Comment: Gotta say: that's an awesome feature in a time where you can ask LLMs to give you improved versions of code-parts and you wanna compare if there are actually nice ideas within the result while checking that critical parts have remained unchanged!!!